# Why the sound stopped working?

Tags: 12.10, sound

My sound suddenly stopped to work today at my Ubuntu 12.10.

1. The ubuntu recognize the recording in *Settings* -> *Sound* -> *Input*
2. I already tried to remove `.pulse` and `.pulse-cookie`
3. I tried to reinstall `.pulse` and `ansa` via the synaptic
4. When I plugged-in earphones it **works**
5. there is no mute channel via `alsamixer`
6. I tried to reboot few times
7. I also try it via Ubuntu live(12.10 via usb-drive) - same results

Is it possible it a hardware problem? or maybe we can fix it with the geeky style :)?

Thanks

Comment: To check if your sound levels are correct (or that the speakers are enabled), run `alsamixer` from a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by checking the sound via the bios(thanks to great dell support!) its seems the its speaker problem :(

Anyway- thanks everyone for great suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you plug in a 3.5mm headset and see if the sound works.

If it doesn't, it might be a software problem.

If it does, then your speakers might be broken.

I hope this helps.